# How can I terminate my program with one character?

Tags: c, string, input

I am asked to take the first and second name from a user and search for it in a file. I am also asked to terminate when the user enters the character 'x' or 'X'.

```
printf("\nEnter the name and surname for WHR calculation (Exit - X): ");
scanf("%s %s",name,surname);

while(strcmp(name,'X')==0 ||strcmp(name,'x')==0){
    printf("BYE!!\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

It should display "BYE" and terminate the program but when I type in the first `x` and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> nothing happens until I type in `x` again and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: Always compile with `-Wall` and `-Wextra`, and don't ignore the warnings.

Comment: `name` is a string and you're using a function that should compare it to a string. But it does not: 'X' is NOT a string.

Answer (score 1):

You will close with 1 character but followed by new line (Enter):

```
if ( tolower( name[0] ) == 'x' && name[1] == 0 )
{
    printf( "BYE!\n" );
    exit( 1 );
}
```

No need from `while` loop and `strcmp` has to compare to `"x"` not `'x'` but it is longer than simple char comparison. PS: `tolower` will need `#include <ctype.h>`.

Comment: why do we need name[1]==0 in the if condition ?!

Comment: `name[1] == 0` is necessary to check for single "X" letter. Otherwise if you check only `name[0]` the input can be "XYZ" and the program will terminate as well. With `name[1] == 0` it will stop only after "X" or "x" followed by Enter key. PS: I hope you have `while` loop around `printf` / `scanf` / `if` block, to ensure multiple calls until "X".

Answer (score 1):

Use a `do while` loop, this keeps asking for input until the user enters `"x"` or `"X"`. The `do while` loop is ideal as the while **condition** is at the **end** of the loop, meaning that the loop will always execute at *least* once per program execution. It will then continue to ask the user for input until the user inputs the mentioned strings (x or X).

```
do {
    printf("\nEnter the name and surname for WHR calculation (Exit - X): ");
    scanf("%s %s",name,surname);

    // Do more work here...

} while((strcmp(name, "X") != 0) && (strcmp(name, "x") != 0));

// Finish program
printf("BYE!!\n");
exit(1);
```

Note that `strcmp()` requires `string.h` to be included.

Answer (score 1):

There are several basic mistake are here:-

First instead of if you are using while , it is better to use if here

second you are comparing character  'X' or 'x' with string

I am running below code working for me

```
char name[100], surname[100];
printf("\nEnter the name and surname for WHR calculation (Exit - X): ");
scanf("%s %s",name,surname);

printf("\n%s surname %s \n", name ,surname);
if(strcmp(name,"X")==0 ||strcmp(name,"x")==0){
    printf("BYE!!\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: the problem is that when I type in the first x and hit enter nothing happens until i type in x again and hit enter !!

Answer (score 1):

This code waits for the user to enter two words, separated by spaces/newlines:

```
scanf("%s %s",name,surname);
```

The system will not continue executing your other code until it gets from the user what it wants - two words - or an error happens (e.g. user can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

It seems that you want to allow the user to supply "x" for `name` and exit immediately. So you should split your input code:

```
scanf("%s",name);
scanf("%s",surname);
```

And cram the code that checks for `x` in-between:

```
scanf("%s",name);
if(strcmp(name,"X")==0 ||strcmp(name,"x")==0){
    printf("BYE!!\n");
    exit(1);
}
scanf("%s",surname);
```

If you want to check both name and surname (maybe the user entered his surname as `x` in order to exit), you should either duplicate the code or stuff it into a function:

```
scanf("%s",name);
check_for_x(name);
scanf("%s",surname);
check_for_x(surname);

...

void check_for_x(const char *str)
{
    if(strcmp(str,"X")==0 ||strcmp(str,"x")==0){
        printf("BYE!!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're a genius!!